# i want to make my code responsive to any screen sizes flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, responsiveness

i want to make my application responsive to any screen size by the way i tried to use flexible Mediaquery and make my code on a container That i put it inside a row

but when i Try It on my mobile phone It look supper Nice and in another phones It look So Bad and big
so how can i make it responsive with any screen size ,
ps: when i debug it in any scren it look nice but when i releasse it to convert it to apk and try it to another phone it look so bad and not responsive

```html
import 'package:ecofun_ui/screens/details_screen.dart';
import 'package:ecofun_ui/widget/category-card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'slide.dart';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';

//import 'package:bubble_bottom_bar/bubble_bottom_bar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SplashPage(duration: 3, goToPage: WelcomePage())));
}

//start the splash page
class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  int duration = 0;
  Widget goToPage;
  SplashPage({this.goToPage, this.duration});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: this.duration), () {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => this.goToPage));
    });
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: LogoWhite()));
  }
} //the end of splashpage screen

//start the welcome screen
class WelcomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
          heightFactor: 1,
          widthFactor: 1,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (ctx, constraints) {
                return Column(children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.15,
                  ),
                  Text('E c o F u n',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                          fontSize: 60,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.1,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
                        },
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                        color: Colors.deepOrange,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 15, bottom: 15, left: 70, right: 70),
                        child: AutoSizeText(
                          ' نادي الرقي ',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28, color: Colors.white),
                          maxLines: 1,
                        ),
                      )),
                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          child: Material(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              child: InkWell(
                                splashColor: Colors.deepOrange.withOpacity(0.2),
                                highlightColor:
                                    Colors.deepOrange.withOpacity(0.2),
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      right: 70, left: 70, top: 15, bottom: 15),
                                  child: AutoSizeText(
                                    'حساب المعدل',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 28, color: Colors.deepOrange),
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                  ),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: Colors.deepOrange,
                                        width: 3,
                                      )),
                                ),
                              )))),
                  Container(
                    height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.3,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage("images/teamspirit.gif"),
                            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth)),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.01,
                        width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.2,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.02,
                      ),
                      AutoSizeText(
                        'All right reserved for EcoClub\n Devlopped by Imen Lakrib',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black),
                        maxLines: 2,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ]);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]));
  } //the end of welcome screen
}

class LogoWhite extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        child: Image.asset(
          "images/logowhite.png",
          //fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ));
  }
}

// onboarding class with widgets
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _currentPage = 0;
  PageController _controller = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3084AC),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 500 / 100),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(40), topRight: Radius.circular(40))),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              // Pageview
              PageView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  onPageChanged: _onchanged,
                  controller: _controller,
                  itemCount: _pages.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                    return _pages[index];
                  }),

              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: List<Widget>.generate(_pages.length, (int index) {
                      return AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        height: 6,
                        width: (index == _currentPage) ? 20 : 10,
                        margin:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 30),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            color: (index == _currentPage)
                                ? Colors.blue
                                : Colors.orange),
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      _controller.nextPage(
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                          curve: Curves.easeInOutQuint);
                    },
                    child: AnimatedContainer(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        height: 44,
                        width: 217,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Color(0xFF263238).withOpacity(0.5),
                                  blurRadius: 4,
                                  spreadRadius: 1)
                            ]),
                        child: (_currentPage == (_pages.length - 1))
                            ? Text(
                                "Get Started",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                ),
                              )
                            : Text(
                                "Next",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                ),
                              )),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 11,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // generate Page View
  List<Widget> _pages = [
    SliderPage(
      title: "من نحن",
      descreption:
          "أول نادي ثقافي علمي بجامعة الجزائر 3 \n  تم انشاءه من قبل طلبة اختلفت افكارهم \n واجتمع حب المبادرة لديهم والرغبة في التغيير \n وترك الاثر في الجامعة",
      beginColor: Color(0xFFB6E3F3),
      endColor: Color(0xFF061922),
      bgscreen: "images/screen_1.png",
    ),
    SliderPage(
      title: "اهدافنا",
      descreption:
          "مرافقة الطالب وتشجيعه وتحفيزه لان يكون \n طالبا مثقفا ملما بتخصصه او بما له صلة به ",
      beginColor: Color(0xFFB469EC),
      endColor: Color(0xFF3E165B),
      bgscreen: "images/screen_2.png",
    ),
    SliderPage(
      title: "رؤيتنا",
      descreption:
          "تاهيل وتجهيز الطالب للحياة المهنية \n ليكون مسلحا بالمهارات التي يطلبها سوق العمل",
      beginColor: Color(0xFF79E69F),
      endColor: Color(0xFF136A33),
      bgscreen: "images/screen_3.png",
    ),
    SliderPage(
      title: "شعارنا",
      descreption: "رسخ فكرة .. جسد عملا .. اترك اثرا",
      beginColor: Color(0xFF79E69F),
      endColor: Color(0xFF136A33),
      bgscreen: "images/screen_5.png",
    ),
    SliderPage(
      title: "انظم لنا",
      descreption:
          "ان كنت طالبا تزاول دراستك حاليا \n  باحدى كليات جامعة الجزائر 3 \n  ماعليك الا مراسلتنا على مختلف صفحاتنا",
      beginColor: Color(0xFF79E69F),
      endColor: Color(0xFF136A33),
      bgscreen: "images/screen_4.png",
    )
  ];
  _onchanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentPage = index;
    });
  }
}

//the end of onboarding class with widgets

// calcsecreen start
class CalcScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        //bottomNavigationBar: BubbleBottomBar(),

        body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: size.height * 1,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.orange,
              image: DecorationImage(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  image: AssetImage("images/bgorange.png"))),
        ),
        SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 25,
              ),
              Text(
                'مرحبا بكم في \n برنامج حساب المعدلات',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .display1
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: 1,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CategoryCard(
                    title: 'ماستر 1',
                    image: "images/M1.png",
                    press: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return FifthYear();
                        }),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  CategoryCard(
                    title: 'ماستر 2',
                    image: "images/M2.png",
                    press: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return FordYear();
                        }),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  CategoryCard(
                    title: '1 ليسانس',
                    image: "images/L1.png",
                    press: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return SecondS1();
                        }),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  CategoryCard(
                    title: '2 ليسانس',
                    image: "images/L2.png",
                    press: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return SecondYear();
                        }),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  CategoryCard(
                    title: '3 ليسانس',
                    image: "images/L3.png",
                    press: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return ThirdYear();
                        }),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ))
            ],
          ),
        ))
      ],
    ));
  }
}

// calcsecreen end
```

Comment: did you latter solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) package, for responsive font you can use like this

```
   Text(
     '16sp, will not change with the system.',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 16.sp, // this will make font responsive
      ),
    ),
```

for responsive UI you can use like this

```
//for example:

///If you want to display a square:
///The UI may show a rectangle:
Container(
   width: 375.w,
   height: 375.h,
 ),
            
////If you want to display a square:
Container(
  width: 300.w,
  height: 300.w,
),

or

Container(
  width: 300.r,
  height: 300.r,
),
```

Or you can identify device type with below code

```
  static bool isMobile(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 650;

  static bool isTablet(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 1100 &&
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 650;

  static bool isDesktop(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1100;
```